# Firestore -- io.grpc.StatusException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building chat application with backend firestore database with below structure.

[image]

I am fetching the data as mention below. Which return the list of channels my user id involve in field "userArray" and to fetch "lastUpdatedOn" data based on given date/time.

```
registration = fireStoreDb.collection(clsUtility.RootCollections.Channels.toString())
            .whereArrayContains("userArray", loggedInPsno)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("lastUpdatedOn", lastChannelUpdateDateTime)
            .orderBy("lastUpdatedOn", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("loadUsers", "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
```

Here in above case, it show me an error in android logcat that to create composite index. Creation of composite index done but still getting same error message.

[image]

> 2019-10-04 17:46:30.562 26824-27054/net.jayamsoft.chat W/Firestore: (21.1.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(Channels where userArray array_contains 90348324 and lastUpdatedOn >= Timestamp(seconds=1570189540, nanoseconds=484000000) order by lastUpdatedOn, **name**) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/easychat-lthe/database/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck5wcm9qZWN0cy9lYXN5Y2hhdC1sdGhlL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9DaGFubmVscy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoNCgl1c2VyQXJyYXkYARoRCg1sYXN0VXBkYXRlZE9uEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ, cause=null}
>   2019-10-04 17:46:30.567 26824-26824/net.jayamsoft.chat W/loadUsers: Listen failed.
>       com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/easychat-lthe/database/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck5wcm9qZWN0cy9lYXN5Y2hhdC1sdGhlL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9DaGFubmVscy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoNCgl1c2VyQXJyYXkYARoRCg1sYXN0VXBkYXRlZE9uEAEaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAQ
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:121)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:131)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:378)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.handleRejectedListen(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:307)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:551)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:436)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:53)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:176)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:108)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:38)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:119)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$2.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:67)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:110)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:120)
>           at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
>           at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
>           at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:563)
>           at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
>           at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:224)

Answer (score 2):

Following the links to generate indexes that the error gives you should be the solution to your issue. It seems the error is requiring you to create 2 indexes.

Attempt to follow the exact links from the error and allow it to create the indexes.

That should work.

Let us know.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yes you are right it required two indexes to be created from the link suggested by Firestore itself. But the issue was, as soon you click on the mention url. it redirect you to Firebase Console with https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/easychat-lthe/database/firestore/indexes?create_composite=xxxxxx link... If you can observe the link carefully, it contains **0** --> where as if i try to create the index manually, it shows me some other number based on my project. in my case it was **25** and that was the issue. I replace the 0 with 25 and run the url :)

Answer (score 0):

Key must not repeat in JSON of firebase 
"lastUpdatedOn"

Comment: Hai Vipul, Yes the key "lastUpdatedOn" is repeating in child collection. As suggested i have changed it but still getting the same result.